# Trying to make bot DM me when someone uses a certain command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When someone uses the shelp command, I want the bot to DM myself saying that they used the command. I tried to make it do that but when I type the command, the bot doesn't DM me. I don't get any errors on startup or when I type the command. How can I get my bot to do this? Thanks in advance! The code below is the code that I got so far.

```
@bot.command()
async def shelp(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Suici** Hotlines", description="US - 800-273-8255, Canada - 833-456-4566, Mexico - 55-5259-8121, Ireland - 116 123 OR text HELLO to 50808, Australia - 13 11 14 United Kingdom - 01708 765200. Remember that you are LOVED! You can do this, we believe in you! If you dont see your country above, please open a support ticket and we will find the # for you.", color=0x00FFFF)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)

  user = bot.get_user('467715040087244800') #my discord id
  await bot.send_message(user, f"{ctx.author.name} used the shelp command in {ctx.guild.name}!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098057/how-to-make-a-discord-py-bot-private-direct-message-someone-whos-not-the-author) for reference

That would require you have the member object of the person you want to dm, in this case, you. That can be done with your ID (Get it with Developer Mode, can be toggle in Appearance Settings) and `fetch_user`, like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def dmcole(ctx):
    user_id = Your_Id
    user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
    channel = await user.create_dm()
    await channel.send("Hey!")
```

Answer (score 1):

`bot.send_message` is depreciated, use `user.send` instead.

```py
await user.send(f"{ctx.author.name} used the shelp command in {ctx.guild.name}!")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and changed the bot.send_message to user.send BUT the bot still does not DM me. When I type the command, it still works just not the DM part. I also don't get any errors.

Comment: Are you using your id as an integer? or a string

Comment: I already got it working with the other answer. But thanks!